# How to get html video controls inside the video window

Tags: html, video

Sorry if this has been asked before (I definitely tried searching). I have an HTML video embedded on a page, and the player controls are displaying outside the video window. I'd like to get them inside the video window, but I can't seem to find any customization available for the controls attribute.

I know the HTML `<video>` tag isn't very customizable, but I've seen many HTML videos display in the desired way (with controls *inside* the video window, not outside), so I assume it's possible.

Example of what I'm trying to do: http://easyhtml5video.com/

How it currently looks:
[image: img]

Comment: What browser are you using? It appears inside by default for me: http://jsfiddle.net/prankol57/pw8jgp4h/

Comment: Can you post some HTML? If not, [this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/building-custom-controls-for-html5-videos) seems to show many ways to customize your HTML5 video playback.

Comment: i'm using chrome by default. but to clarify, how it appears on http://easyhtml5video.com/ is what i'm looking for (and that does display inside for me). The attached image is my current project, which is not displaying inside, unfortunately

Comment: the html for the video right now is:

<video controls id="videoelement" width="480" height="360" style="margin:auto; padding-left:107px" webkit-playsinline>
   
</video>

Comment: @rom-dos Can you post a jsfiddle? Also, what is the size of the actual video (I doubt it matters, but it may be important)?

Comment: I'm seeing it inside as well on Chrome, check your browser settings maybe?

Comment: @rom-dos Nevermind, I see http://jsfiddle.net/prankol57/pw8jgp4h/2/

Comment: @soktinpk sorry, jsfiddle for my video code: http://jsfiddle.net/r3z047hq/ dimensions 480x360

Comment: @rom-dos Are you sure about that? http://jsfiddle.net/prankol57/r3z047hq/1/ (same code, but with a border around the video). The controls *are* inside the element for a video of `480*360`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the `height` attribute is the problem.

Without the height attribute:

```html
<video controls="" id="videoelement" width="480" style="margin:auto; padding-left:107px" webkit-playsinline="">
    <source src="http://easyhtml5video.com/images/happyfit2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://easyhtml5video.com/images/happyfit2.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="http://easyhtml5video.com/images/happyfit2.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

With height attribute:

```html
<video controls="" id="videoelement" width="480" height="360" style="margin:auto; padding-left:107px" webkit-playsinline="">
    <source src="http://easyhtml5video.com/images/happyfit2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://easyhtml5video.com/images/happyfit2.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="http://easyhtml5video.com/images/happyfit2.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

The `height` attribute should be the actual `height` of the video.

Comment: removing the height attribute entirely gave me the results i wanted. thanks!

Comment: @rom-dos If this answer helped you, consider accepting it (checking that checkmark over there beneath the upvote/downvote buttons). There is no obligation to do this (you don't have to if you don't want to).

Answer (score 0):

`height` of your `video` tag should match the height of the actual video resolution....

here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pw8jgp4h/1/)

In this the video resolution is `604px X 256px`
If the video tag has `604x256` then the controls stay within, if I changed the `height` to `356` as demonstrated in the fiddle, then the controls are going outside the video.

You might want to check your video resolution and compare it with the height of your video tag.

Not sure if width matters though.